# Selenium Video recorder working fine-But video showing as blank(black screen) most of the time in windows 10 machine

Tags: selenium

IF I play the recorded video it is showing black color

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found the solution for it? I have tried to provide recording access to my machine. But still didn't work.

Comment: I didnt get any fix for this. I think it is not related selenium in the VM or our machine we have to change some settings